# How to get dynamic values by id -jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Actually, I have a field name (industry) the problem is that I want to get two value from the database change of industry by jquery but how do I do this can't understand. Please help-

Here is my code-

```
 <label>Select Type of Industry</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="industry" id="industry"  onchange="industry_id(this.value);" required="">
          <option value="">------------------Select Your Industry----------------</option> 
           <?php 
                          foreach ($industry as $key => $value) { ?>
                          <option value="<?= $value['id']; ?> "> <?= $value['industory']; ?></option>    
                    <?php } ?> 
          </select> 
  </div> 
  <script>
                 function industry_id(value) {
                   $.get("<?php echo base_url()?>dive/getebitvalue/"+value,function (data) {
                        $("#ebit_name").html(data);
                        // alert(data);
                      });
                    }
                  </script>
```

one value I get easily but how to get second from the same id?

Here is my model---

```
function getebit()
    {
        $industry=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $sql = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM industry WHERE id='.$industry);
        $result = $sql->result();
        $html='';
        foreach ($result as $data) {
            $html.= "<option value='" . $data->ebit . "' >" . $data->ebit  . "</option>";
        }
        echo $html;
    }

}
```

and here is my controller--

```
function getebitvalue(){
        $data['ebit']= $this->site_model->getebit();
    }
```

Comment: show your `getebitvalue` method

Comment: "second from the same id"...the second what, exactly? Please clarify what you're expecting to happen, and what currently happens.

Comment: I m expecting that when I change the industry then I get ebit and edita value from the database but right now I only get ebit value on industry change.

Comment: then you have to return also the second value, u r just returning options values , how u want to return the second value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can also do this-

view page-



    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Type of Industry</label>
          <select class="form-control industryData" name="industry" id="industry"  required="">
          <option value="">------------------Select Your Industry----------------</option> 
           <?php 
                          foreach ($industry as $value) { ?>
                          <option data1="<?php echo $value['ebitda']; ?>" data2="<?php echo $value['ebit']; ?>" value="<?= $value['id']; ?>"> <?= $value['industory']; ?></option>    
                    <?php } ?> 
          </select> 
      </div> 


model page-


    function select($tbl,$con=''){
            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from($tbl);
            if(!empty($con))
                $this->db->where($con);

            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }


controller page-




public function dive(){
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $data['industry'] = $this->site_model->select('industry');
        $this->load->view('dive/dive',$data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }



Now use jquery on your view page--

    <script>

    $(document).on("change", ".industryData", function () {
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    var data1 = $('.industryData option:selected ').attr('data1'); 
    var data2 = $('.industryData option:selected ').attr('data2'); 

    alert(data1);

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method `getebitvalue` in controller should be like this :**

```
function getebitvalue()
{
    $industry_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $result = $this->site_model->getebit($industry_id);
    $html='';
    if ( !empty($result)){
      foreach ($result as $item) 
      {
        $edita[$key] = $item->edita;
        $html.= "<option value='" . $item->ebit . "' >" . $item->ebit  . "</option>";
      }
      $data['edita'] = $edita;
      $data['html'] = $html;
      print_r($data);
      exit;
    }
}
```

Here is your model---

```
function getebit($industry_id)
{
   $sql = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM industry WHERE id='.$industry);
   $result = $sql->result();
   return $result;
}
```